# Vue.js Syntax Highlight in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js

I'm using Visual Studio 2015
I have install Vue.js Pack.
But IDE doesn't support highlight  Vue.js syntax .
What else plugin can I install in VS 2015?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vetur and VueVSCode Snippets. 
Pretty good so far.

[image]